# How to implement the Android rating bar in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native

I didn't see this component in the current components or in the roadmap of future RN official components. Do we have to implement native modules for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll have to roll your own [RatingBar for Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html)

When/If you do, be sure to share it with the community on https://react.parts/native

Answer (score 0):

This is the used for Bot android & IOS also

```
<StarRating 
  disabled={false}
  maxStars={5}
  rating={this.state.starCount}
  selectedStar={(rating) => this.onStarRatingPress(rating)}
/>
```

[Here](https://github.com/djchie/react-native-star-rating) you can find module refference.